# IPFS transaction cost as a decentralized service

Tags: blockchain, ipfs

How much will IPFS charge the fess as a service? Won't it be expensive than existing centralized storage? How can it be used in profitable way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPFS itself does not have transaction cost, nor does it has any promise it provides for storage built-in.

Maybe you refer to [FileCoin](https://filecoin.io/) which will be a service on-top of IPFS which will offer storage service. The price of which I'm not sure anyone exactly knows right now.

Comment: Thank you for answer.  Can you tell me how can i make sure the ipfs store the file i upload and not delete?

Comment: IPFS is only the protocol, it is not a service like DropBox or Google Drive. It's like asking how can you make sure HTTP will store your file, it will not. The idea is that other companies will use IPFS to build service, like FileCoin, to allow distributed file storage.

Comment: But IPFS can be used to store files directly. It have service functionality built in.

Comment: the functionality is built it, but as you can guess, if you had a free way to store things, everyone will just use it :) IPFS provide the functionality, but the incentive to store the data depend on external elements.